# How to implement facebook account-kit instant verification in android?

Tags: android, facebook, account-kit

how can i perform login without OTP verification using facebook account kit.

i have successfully implemented account-kit through SMS verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to place release Key Hash for your app on facebook dashboard.